# JavaScript indexOf() returns -1 for recognized objects in array

Tags: javascript, object, indexof

While create the skeleton for an HTML 5 game (using canvas), I noticed an interesting quirk about the JavaScript language that I don't seem to quite understand!

Specifically, I created an array of objects (nodes) which I have no problem passing through functions (as "node"), but even after confirming that said object is recognized in the console log, the `.indexOf()` method doesn't seem to recognize said object as an item in the array (giving me the generic "-1" output).

```js
function StartGame(){
 //Initiating draw variables
 cx = document.getElementById("GameMap")
 seeds = cx.getContext("2d")
 //Resetting nodes
 nodes = []
 GenNodes() //randomly generates and scatters new connector nodes on the game-map
}

function GenNodes() {
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  nodes[i]= new SeedNode()
  }
}

function SeedNode() {
  this.shape = "circle"
  this.radius = "10"
  this.x = 730*Math.random() + 10
  this.y = 730*Math.random() + 10
  DrawNode(this,this.x,this.y)
} 

function DrawNode(node,x_cen,y_cen) {
 console.log(node)
 console.log(nodes.indexOf(node))
 seeds.beginPath();
 seeds.arc(x_cen,y_cen,10,0,2*Math.PI);
 seeds.stroke();
 seeds.fillText(nodes.indexOf(node),x_cen,y_cen)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ScatterDots! the StackOverFlow Edition</title>
<script src="ScatterDots.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload='StartGame()'>
 
<canvas id="GameMap" width="750" height="750" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

My (rather unsophisticated) guess is that objects are somehow not a valid input for this array-based method. If this is the case, are there W3C standards-compliant ways to get around this?

Comment: I'm afraid you actually accepted a wrong answer.  If a variable is not declared locally, it will be a global variable by JS interpreter. The real problem is that you try to print an object before it is being added to `nodes`. Please check my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attempt to print the index before the node is being added to `nodes`. You will always get -1. In short, please move `DrawNode` out of `SeedNode`.

```
function GenNodes() {
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        var node = new SeedNode()
        nodes.push(node)
        DrawNode(node,node.x,node.y)
    }
}

function SeedNode() {
    var node = {}
    node.shape = "circle"
    node.radius = "10"
    node.x = 730*Math.random() + 10
    node.y = 730*Math.random() + 10 
    return node 
}
```

Comment: I agree that this is the actual solution, but not just because he attempts to print the index before it's added to `nodes`. He also calls indexOf() here: `seeds.fillText(nodes.indexOf(node),x_cen,y_cen)`.

Comment: Yes. I originally noticed my nodes were all being labeled as "-1" so I inserted another indexOf() method call into the function to confirm it was purely a javascript problem and not something super-weird in canvas. Hence the double-error!

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but he problem seems to lie through out these three functions

```
function GenNodes() {
        // Rest of code
    nodes[i]= new SeedNode()
}

function SeedNode() {
        //Rest of code
        DrawNode(this,this.x,this.y)
} 

function DrawNode(node,x_cen,y_cen) {

    // Rest of code
    console.log(nodes.indexOf(node))
    seeds.fillText(nodes.indexOf(node),x_cen,y_cen)
}
```

In function `GenNodes` you are try to populate the the `nodes` array But this will depend on return from `SeedNode`  function. Again  this `SeenNode` is dependent on return from of `DrawNode` function . That mean once `DrawNode` & `SeedNode` have executed then it will put the element in the `nodes` array. But before putting the element you are  checking the `indexOf` the element in `nodes` array inside `DrawNode`.

So it is returning -1 which I think is right according to this documentation on  [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Nice catch! It didn't even occur to me that I might be prematurely calling the method, but in fact everything is normal when I make a dedicated labeling function AFTER the nodes are created. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a scoping problem. `nodes` is never declared anywhere that `DrawNode()` can find it. To fix it, declare `nodes` outside any function:

```
var testMe = [];
function doSomething() {
  doTheThing();
}

function doTheThing() {
  testMe[0] = "hi";
  testMe[1] = "there";
  doTheOtherThing();
}

function doTheOtherThing() {
  console.log("This works");
  console.log(testMe.indexOf("there"));
}

doSomething();
```

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 is correct and his solution is the right one.

Comment: Thanks for your honesty. In hindsight, my error was quite obvious, so I didn't actually check your specific code!